# Apache + asp.net framework 4 + windows 7

Tags: asp.net, apache

Is this a good idea to run a asp.net website on Apache web-server on Windows platform? 
Any performance hits. 
I am doing this because Apache is free, where as I will have to pay for Windows server 2008.
My site will be medium loaded, and will be targeting currently intranet only.

And if any body knows mod_aspdotnet please explain or some very good link for beginners.
I have already seen this link: http://mod-aspdotnet.sourceforge.net/introduction.html

Do I really need this mod_aspdotnet because Apache server will be installed in Windows platform?

Newbie question but please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: As @NipunAmbastha pointed out, if you want to use Apache as your web server, you should use Mono right now (mod_mono). Microsoft .NET never supports Apache. As an open source project mod_aspdonet hasn't been updated in the past 3 years, so if you still use it you put yourself on risks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this
http://mono-project.com/ASP.NET

But I am not sure why you need Appache, you have IIS in all OS and its free.